# Which one is best between default parameters and member initialisation when declared in private section of a C++14 class?

Tags: c++, c++14

The functionality of both codes is the same but which one is more efficient and why?

here's the regular code:

```
class Account{
private:
    int balance;
    string name;
public:
     Account(int balance = 0, name = "none"); //default parameters
};
```

**or**

this one:

```
class Account{
private:
    int balance{0};
    string name{"none"}; //default values when members are declared
};
```

Comment: The second one.

Comment: The two examples do not do the same ting.  The first doesn't initialize either of the member variables.

Comment: Functionality is not the same.  The 2 default parameter constructor allows `Account a{100};`  Which I guess is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Second one.

Reason :
"Makes it explicit that the same value is expected to be used in all constructors. Avoids repetition. Avoids maintenance problems. It leads to the shortest and most efficient code."

Refer CPP Core guidelines for more details: [C.48: Prefer in-class initializers to member initializers in constructors for constant initializers](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c48-prefer-in-class-initializers-to-member-initializers-in-constructors-for-constant-initializers)